# Use of interface in tx.origin

Tags: vulnerability

I have found a link for replaying tx.origin vulnerability at:

[Unable to replicate tx.origin](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38490/unable-to-replicate-tx-origin-attack)
 I can’t understand the use of interface. Is it necessary to use interface? I am also getting a syntax error in case of interface because it has the same name as the name of user wallet?

Some body please guide me:

1. What is the use of interface in tx.origin vulnerability?
2. Should I not change the name of interface?.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessary. Its use is unrelated to tx.origin vulnerability.

I think the idea of the question was to have two files:

- Victim: contract TxUserWallet
- Attacker: interface TxUserWallet, contract TxAttackWallet